# MPI (Summation)

Tags: c++, mpi, partial

I am writing a program that calculates the sum of every number up to 1000. For example, 1+2+3+4+5....+100. First, I assign summation jobs to 10 processors: Processor 0 gets 1-100, Processor 1 gets 101-200 and so on. The sums are stored in an array.

After all summations have been done parallelly, processors send their values to Processor 0 (Processor 0 receives values using nonblocking send/recv) and Processor 0 sums up all the values and displays the result.

Here is the code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int summation(int, int);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int * array;
    int total_proc;
    int curr_proc;
    int limit = 0;
    int partial_sum = 0;
    int upperlimit = 0, lowerlimit = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &total_proc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &curr_proc);
    MPI_Request send_request, recv_request;

    /* checking if 1000 is divisible by number of procs, else quit */
    if(1000 % total_proc != 0)
    {
        MPI_Finalize();
        if(curr_proc == 0)
            cout << "**** 1000 is not divisible by " << total_proc << " ...quitting..."<< endl;
        return 0;
    }

    /* number of partial summations */
    limit = 1000/total_proc;

    array = new int [total_proc];

    /* assigning jobs to processors */
    for(int i = 0; i < total_proc; i++)
    {
        if(curr_proc == i)
        {
            upperlimit = upperlimit + limit;
            lowerlimit = (upperlimit - limit) + 1;
            partial_sum = summation(upperlimit, lowerlimit);
            array[i] = partial_sum;
        }
        else
        {
            upperlimit = upperlimit + limit;
            lowerlimit = (upperlimit - limit) + 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "** Partial Sum From Process " << curr_proc << " is " << array[curr_proc] << endl;

    /* send and receive - non blocking */
    for(int i = 1; i < total_proc; i++)
    {
        if(curr_proc == i) /* (i = current processor) */
        {
            MPI_Isend(&array[i], 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request);
            cout << "-> Process " << i << " sent " << array[i] << " to Process 0" << endl;

            MPI_Irecv(&array[i], 1, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_request);
            //cout << "<- Process 0 received " << array[i] << " from Process " << i << endl;
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    if(curr_proc == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < total_proc; i++)
            array[0] = array[0] + array[i];
        cout << "Sum is " << array[0] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int summation(int u, int l)
{
    int result = 0; 
    for(int i = l; i <= u; i++)
        result = result + i;
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
** Partial Sum From Process 0 is 5050
** Partial Sum From Process 3 is 35050
-> Process 3 sent 35050 to Process 0
<- Process 0 received 35050 from Process 3
** Partial Sum From Process 4 is 45050
-> Process 4 sent 45050 to Process 0
<- Process 0 received 45050 from Process 4
** Partial Sum From Process 5 is 55050
-> Process 5 sent 55050 to Process 0
<- Process 0 received 55050 from Process 5
** Partial Sum From Process 6 is 65050
** Partial Sum From Process 8 is 85050
-> Process 8 sent 85050 to Process 0
<- Process 0 received 85050 from Process 8
-> Process 6 sent 65050 to Process 0
** Partial Sum From Process 1 is 15050
** Partial Sum From Process 2 is 25050
-> Process 2 sent 25050 to Process 0
<- Process 0 received 25050 from Process 2
<- Process 0 received 65050 from Process 6
** Partial Sum From Process 7 is 75050
-> Process 1 sent 15050 to Process 0
<- Process 0 received 15050 from Process 1
-> Process 7 sent 75050 to Process 0
<- Process 0 received 75050 from Process 7
** Partial Sum From Process 9 is 95050
-> Process 9 sent 95050 to Process 0
<- Process 0 received 95050 from Process 9
Sum is -1544080023
```

Printing the contents of the array:

```
5050
536870912
-1579286148
-268433415
501219332
32666
501222192
32666
1
0
```

I'd like to know what is causing this.

If I print the array before MPI_Finalize is invoked it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important flaw your program has is how you divide the work. In MPI, **every process is executing the main function**. Therefore, you must ensure that all the processes execute your `summation` function if you want them to collaborate on building the result.

You don't need the for loop. Every process is executing the main separately. They just have different `curr_proc` values, and you can compute which portion of the job they have to perform based on that:

```
/* assigning jobs to processors */
int chunk_size = 1000 / total_proc;
lowerlimit = curr_proc * chunk_size;
upperlimit = (curr_proc+1) * chunk_size;
partial_sum = summation(upperlimit, lowerlimit);
```

Then, how the master process receives all the other processes' partial sum is not correct.

- MPI rank values (`curr_proc`) start form 0 up to `MPI_Comm_size` output value (`total_proc-1`).
- Only the process #1 is sending/receiving data.
- You are using the immediate version of send and receive: `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_recv` but you are not waiting until those requests are completed. You should use `MPI_Waitall` for that purpose.

The correct version would be something like the following:

```
if( curr_proc == 0 ) {
   // master process receives all data
   for( int i = 1; i < total_proc; i++ )
      MPI_Recv( &array[i], MPI_INT, 1, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
} else {
   // other processes send data to the master
   MPI_Send( &partial_sum, MPI_INT, 1, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
}
```

This all-to-one communication pattern is known as *gather*. In MPI there is a function which already performs this functionality: `MPI_Gather`.

Finally, what you intent to perform is known as *reduction*: take a given amount of numeric values and generate a single output value by continuously performing a single operation (a sum, in your case). In MPI there is a function which does that, too: `MPI_Reduce`.

I strongly suggest you to do [some basic guided exercises](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/mpiexmpl/contents.html) before trying to make your own. MPI is difficult to understand at the beginning. Building a good base is vital for you to be able to add complexity later on. A [hands on tutorial](https://www.nics.tennessee.edu/mpi-tutorial) is also a good way of getting started into MPI.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that **you don't need to enforce an even divission of the problem size** (1000 in this case) by the number of resources (`total_proc`). Depending on the case, you can either assign the remainder to a single process:

```
chunk_size = 1000 / total_proc;
if( curr_proc == 0 )
    chunk_size += 1000 % total_proc;
```

Or balance it as much as possible:

```
int remainder = curr_proc < ( 1000 % proc )? 1 : 0;
lowerlimit = curr_proc * chunk_size /* as usual */
           + curr_proc;             /* cumulative remainder */
upperlimit = (curr_proc + 1) * chunk_size /* as usual */
           + remainder;                   /* curr_proc remainder */
```

The second case, the load unbalance will be as much as 1, while in the first case the load unbalance can reach `total_proc-1` in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

You're only initializing `array[i]`, the element that corresponds to the `curr_proc` id.  The other elements in that array will be uninitialized, resulting in random values.  In your send/receive print loop, you only access the initialized element.

I'm not that familiar with MPI so I'm guessing, but you might want to allocate `array` before calling `MPI_Init`.  Or call `MPI_Receive` on process 0, not each individual one.