# MPI: Broadcasting by k-ary Replication

Tags: mpi, replication, broadcast

I have to implement a broadcasting algorithm that uses k-ary replication.

```
void mpi_mbroadcast(int fromp, int multi, int degree, char * from, char * to, int nbytes);
```

1) **fromp** is the source processor that holds the message to be broadcast.

2) **multi** is the length of the data structure that is being copied (the structure to be broadcast is an array of multi entries, the size of each entry being nbytes long).

3) **degree** is the degree of replication. Each processor in each superstep would send the received message to at most *degree - 1* other processors.

4) **from** is the base address of the first byte that will be broadcast.

5) **to** is the base address of the first position that will receive the broadcast message.

6) **nbytes** is the size in bytes of the elementary data type (array element) that is being copied.

I have implemented a program that calculates partial sums and sends the sums to Processor 0. Now I have to implement a program that broadcast sums by k-ary replication.

Link: [MPI Summation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671176/mpi-summation/39672096#39672096)

How do I use the function above to send and receive data. (I think it is all-to-all broadcast)?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Yes. Extra Credit. Need the extra credit.